# How to add session timeout in WSO2 IoT Server 3.3.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, wso2, session-timeout, wso2-identity-server

Session timeout for WSO2 IoT Server version 3.3.0 is not working for me.
What should I do to set user session timeout after 15 minutes?

I have added this code in

```
<wso2_server_home>/conf/identity/identity.xml
```

but it won't work.

```
<TimeConfig>
    <SessionIdleTimeout> 15 </SessionIdleTimeout>
</TimeConfig>
```

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Session+Timeout

Comment: Welcome to SO, you could always take the tour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), so that your answer would be more helpful and clean. In our case it looks like the question is broken in pieces, half in question body and half in question comment, but still not quite sure about it. Also i am not sure if you checked the [wso2 docu](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IOTS330/Using+WSO2+IoT+Server), which might be providing some more details regarding the config.